# In a uniaxial crystal, what determines the optical axis, extraordinary axis, and ordinary axis?

Tags: optics, optical-materials, birefringence

In a uniaxial crystal there is an optic axis, an extraordinary axis, and an ordinary axis. The optic axis is not the direction in which we plan to propagate light. The light is propagating in a direction such that the electric field might oscillate parallel to the optic axis. I have included a hand-drawn diagram below.

- What about the crystal determines how the optic axis is oriented?
- Is one of the principal axes (ordinary / extraordinary) always parallel to the optic axis?
- How is the ordinary axis distinguished from the extraordinary?

What happens if I propagate light along the optic axis? In a uniaxial crystal, is there a third refractive index that comes into play?

[image: Diagram showing light propagation vector (k) entering a uniaxial crystal]

Comment: This is a good place to start looking - https://www.rp-photonics.com/birefringence.html

Comment: This is covered reasonably well in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence - "The terms "ordinary" and "extraordinary" are still applied to the polarization components perpendicular to and not perpendicular to the optic axis respectively"

Comment: Thanks for linking these really obscure websites. I never would have thought to look into this on my own. Naturally I posted on stack exchange hoping to receive links to other websites instead of a succinct explanation.